# How to push tango project apk in google play store

Tags: google-project-tango, tango

i want to push one tango project apk into google playstore, what is steps to do it, Is it same like pushing android apk? How can it differentiate as tango?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying applications using the Tango framework to Google Play requires only one additional step to the normal Android distribution process. To make sure your application can only be installed by Tango compatible devices, add the following line to your application's manifest file.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device2" android:required="true" />
```